# Windows 8 metro app identifier not found error

Tags: windows-8, c++-cx

I have three functions declared in my MainPage.xaml.h file:

```
int GetOperator(Platform::String^ str);
bool IsNumber (Platform::String^ str);
bool IsOperator (Platform::String^ str);
```

and use them in my MainPage.cpp file, but get "Identifier not found" error on these three functions in my .cpp file when I try to build.

They are all called by a fourth function, which is also declared in my .h file, but I don't get this error on this fourth function.

Comment: FYI. Metro is a trademark in Germany which is why it got renamed to Windows Store Apps. Just as a small side information.

Comment: Ah, thanks!  Will make an adjustment

Answer (score 0):

First you need to add your header file to your cpp file (and you also need to set the linker in your IDE so the compiler knows where to find the header file)

```
#include "Your_headerfile.h"
```

After that you need to declair the functions also in your .cpp file/code. It is called forward declaration. The compiler needs to know the function prototype when the function call is compiled.

```
int GetOperator(Platform::String^ str);
bool IsNumber (Platform::String^ str);
bool IsOperator (Platform::String^ str);

int main()
{
   ...
   your code
   ...
}
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?